# Faster Deserialization in Python

Tags: python, serialization

What do you think is the fastest deserialization method?
Pickle? YAML? or JSONPickle?

Comment: When using `cPickle` (use that instead of `pickle`!), be sure to use the `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`.

Comment: There's nothing to think--just test it yourself and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd imagine [**cPickle**](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/module-cPickle.html) would be the fastest method of serialisation, though it's just an (educated) guess. It's written in pure C, with Python bindings, and uses a binary format for storing objects, thus should be pretty fast!

Comment: yes cpickle is the best but i cannot use c extensions in AppEngine where i am deploying :)

Comment: Ah, that kind of sucks. Just test pickle and see if it's good/efficient enough for your purposes, perhaps? I love how easy it is to use.